# Very low sound in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, speakers

Been googleing around for a few days now on that problem, nothing seems to work.

The sound coming out of the speakers is very, VERY low. It does so since I updated to Windows 10 and then resetted to factory status via windows 10. So low that you can hear it only if there's no other sounds and really concentrate on hearing it. I tested, and it's not white audio, it's really the right sound.

I blame this on realtek HD sound (the basic Windows sound driver).

Here's what I tried.

1. Plugged my phone in my speakers, played music, came out of the speakers normally (with good sound.)
2. Plugged headphones instead in the jack instead of the speakers, no sound in the headphones too.
3. Front jack works fine.

So I know the problem comes from the back jack port, and not my audio setup.

Realtek Audio HD seems normal:
[image]

The sound manager seems normal too.
[image]

EDIT: Also tried to update the drivers.

Comment: Same issue, no solution ...

Comment: Uninstall Realtek audio driver in the device panel and reboot.
The generic audio driver have a normal sound level.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Assuming you have vanilla Realtek audio,** this should work to some extent.

1. Open the **Sound** menu (as shown in your second screenshot).
2. Right-click on your speakers (or the audio output you want to amplify), and select **Properties**.
3. Go to the **Enhancements** tab.
4. Check the **Loudness Equalization** option.

This makes quiet sounds louder, loud sounds quieter.

Comment: I dont have Lodness Equalization option. What did I miss?

Answer (score 10):

At the Sound Manager, like the one pictured above, click on "communications", then click on "Do Nothing". That should solve the low volume problem.

Good Luck

Comment: That doesn't solve anything :-(

Comment: Solves when the sound goes out when you start a Skype Call or some other, equivalent actions.

Comment: I have been having what appeared to be random volume issues with my speakers and this fixed it. Dunno what WIndows thinks was skype-call-ish.

Comment: This did it for me! It happend before I've used Steams Voice Chat, then used other apps and it felt quieter. Thing got worse unpluging the mic a couple of times and ended up crancking the thing to 11. Read this old question and got me thinking, instead of doing that I closed Steam and that did the trick and got me grooving in no time Your method works because apps call this system function and if said app fails on closing this call you get stuck with low volume. You can change the system behavior or close the app. Cheers

Comment: This fixed it for me!

Comment: I love you. Even five years later.

Comment: ...Now to figure out what in the world is using my comms ports....

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility (from [Matthew Scheffel](https://superuser.com/users/1783356/matthew-scheffel)):

If you:

- are using windows
- are using headphones
- find the audio far too quiet sometimes
- find the audio just fine other times

try restarting the Windows Audio service.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a surround capable sound driver, even if you have it configured for stereo channels only, check your volume balance sliders. The front channels might be set to a lower volume than the unused surround channels:

[image: Windows' speaker properties dialog, with volume at full but front left and front right volume channels at 5%]

Answer (score 0):

I had the sames issue, and I resolved it by checking Windows Sonic for Headphones (view image)[image]