# Windows 10 volume goes low after updating to latest update ver 2004

Tags: windows-10, audio, updates, windows-10-upgrade

I just updated windows 10 to build version 2004 and now my sound volume is lower.

I tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/948954/very-low-sound-in-windows-10) and [this](https://windowsreport.com/pc-sound-volume-too-low/) and all failed to work. And I don't have the "Loudness Equalization" although I'm using Realtek audio.

Comment: Did you update to the newest audio driver.  Does your Realtek have Dolby and was that uninstalled by Windows?   Update BIOS as well.

Comment: If you revert back to the previous version does the problem still exist?

Answer (score 0):

Try the realtek audio console from the windows 10 store.
It has loudness equalization in it